# PHP Fatal error: Class 'SmartySecurity' not found

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Been pulling my hair for 2 hours on this Smarty 2.6 to Smarty 3.1 upgrade task for that old website.  The reason is that the host is now PHP 7 only.  No more PHP 5.  I thought it would be a 1 hour deal, but it's quickly turning into a nightmare.  I remember using Smarty back in 2005 and I've never used it ever again, but today, nearly 15 years later, this monstrosity of a template engine is haunting me back!

Here's the init PHP file's contents:

```
<?php

#Load Smarty library
#require_once("php/Smarty-2.6.26/libs/Smarty.class.php");
#require_once("php/smarty-3.1.34/libs/Smarty.class.php");
require_once("php/smarty-3.1.34/libs/SmartyBC.class.php");
require_once("php/smarty-3.1.34/libs/sysplugins/smarty_security.php");

class class_init extends SmartyBC {

    function __construct(){
        #Init
        parent::__construct();

        #Directories
        $this->template_dir = "skin/".SKIN."/public/";
        $this->compile_dir  = "skin/".SKIN."/compile/";
        $this->config_dir   = "skin/".SKIN."/config/";
        $this->cache_dir    = "skin/".SKIN."/cache/";

        #Caching
        $this->caching          = (boolean)SMARTY_CACHING;
        $this->cache_lifetime   = (int)SMARTY_CACHE_LIFETIME;
        $this->debugging        = true;
    }

    function is_cached($str_tpl, $cache_id = NULL, $compile_id = NULL){
        return $this->isCached($str_tpl, $cache_id, $compile_id);
    }
}

class MySecurity extends SmartySecurity {
    public $secure_dir = array('/home/lesclownsducarro/public_html/'); 

    public function __construct(Smarty $smarty){
        parent::__construct($smarty);
    }
}


?>
```

Here's the controller file's contents:

```
require_once("./php/class/init.php");
$_ENV['class_init'] = new class_init();
$securityPolicy = new Smarty_Security($_ENV['class_init']);
$securityPolicy->php_handling = \Smarty::PHP_ALLOW;
$_ENV['class_init']->enableSecurity($securityPolicy);
```

Getting a completely blank page and the error_log simply states:

```
[30-Dec-2019 22:22:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SmartySecurity' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/php/class/init.php on line 32
```

FOR BACKWARDS COMPATIBILITY, I need to use SmartyBC because the template is including PHP files all over the place.  inb4 yes I know, and this is not my website.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

DOH.  Welp, I'm just too tired, it seems.

It should obviously be: `$securityPolicy = new Smarty_Security($_ENV['class_init']);`

**...with the underscore**.  I don't know, I copy/pasted the example from smarty.net without paying any attention at all.  "new SmartySecurity" as seen here: https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=72741

JFC.

Comment: My bike is two tired as well.